# NLTK consolidating frequently occuring ngrams in a wildcard manner

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following code that finds frequently occuring ngrams in a large text file:

```
import operator
import codecs
import nltk

f = codecs.open('e:/nltk_data/corpora/en/english.txt','r','utf-8')
raw = f.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
bgs = nltk.ngrams(tokens, 6)
#compute frequency distribution for all the ngrams in the text
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(bgs)
s = sorted(fdist.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for i in range(200):
    print s[i][1], s[i][0][0], s[i][0][1], s[i][0][2], s[i][0][3], s[i][0][4], s[i][0][5]
```

Does anyone know how to write a function that can consolidate the results as per the following example:

```
20 a province in South Africa
30 a province in Greater America
50 a province in Eastern China
```

Consolidated into:

```
100 a province in <thing1> <thing2>
```

Or

```
10 America is a country
20 China is a country
```

Consolidated into:

```
30 <thing> is a country
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you want to do. What is the criteria to group the n-grams from the output? It is just that 3 words are the repeated in the n-gram? Or the words to remove have to really be a "thing"? For example, "10 as per the following example" and "20 look at the following example" would be "30 <word1> <word2> the following example"?

Comment: The fact that the words are repeated and the things are not repeated, yes.

Comment: Ok. I thought you were interested in the semantics, but I see you are not. But anyway, that would be what you would get of a n-gram of smaller order, a n-gram 3 for example? I still don't really get what you are trying to obtain, sorry.

Comment: But my way would automatically relate the ngram to the trigram, whereas running trigrams would not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a full solution to your problem, but after exchange of comments, and playing a bit around myself, I post the code I've got in case it gives you a starting point.

I don't have your input file, I've created one simple and short and applied your code to it. I get these 6-grams:

```
2 and quiet nights at home .
2 quiet nights at home . Seeking
1 dining out , movies , bbqs.
1 , caring woman , slim or
1 an honest , caring woman ,
1 bike riding , TV and DVDs
1 honest lady for friendship to relationship
1 , movies , bbqs. , football
1 with similar interests for friend ship/relationship
1 , country drives and quiet nights
1 . Am honest , caring ,
```

and many more with 1 occurency only.

The following code gets the 3-grams inside the 6-grams (only if the 6-gram has more than one occurrence).

```
In [17]:

inter_grams = {}
for i in range(10):
    if s[i][1] > 1:
        for inter_gram in list(nltk.ngrams(s[i][0], 3)):
            #print inter_gram
            if inter_gram in inter_grams.keys():
                inter_grams[inter_gram] += s[i][1]
            else:
                inter_grams[inter_gram] = s[i][1]
​
print inter_grams
{('nights', 'at', 'home'): 4, ('at', 'home', '.'): 4, ('and', 'quiet', 'nights'): 2, ('quiet', 'nights', 'at'): 4, ('home', '.', 'Seeking'): 2}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't really do what I want, but certainly is helpfull